# Output of C program involving pre/post increment and pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I was a solving *guess output of following C code* quiz, where I didnt get the output of below one:

(In comments following `printf`s I have written the execution sequence that I think that line has executed in and what confuses me)

```
    int i;
    int *ptr = (int *) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    int *ptr2 = ptr;
    int *ptr3 = ptr;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        *(ptr + i) = i;
    }
    printf("%d ", *ptr++);   //*ptr evaluated to 0, print 0, increment ptr 
    printf("%d ", (*ptr)++); //*ptr evaluated to 1, print 1, increment ptr
    printf("%d ", *ptr);     //*ptr evaluated to 2, print 2
    printf("%d ", *++ptr);   //increment ptr, *ptr evaluated to 3, print 3 (but in actual it prints 2, why?)
    printf("%d ", ++*ptr);   //*ptr evaluated to 3, increment 3, print 4 (but in actual it prints 3, why?)
```

Output

```
0 1 2 2 3
```

Why the last two integers 2 and 3? I felt they should be 3 and 4.

[Here](https://ideone.com/4gl87X) is ideone link.

Comment: Hint: `(*ptr)++` doesn't increment the pointer, it increments what it points at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*ptr++
```

Increment `ptr` and then dereference the previous value of `ptr`, yielding `ptr[0]` (0).

```
(*ptr)++
```

Dereference `ptr` and then increment the value stored there, yielding `ptr[1]` (1) (but leaving it as 2).

```
*ptr
```

Dereference the pointer, yielding `ptr[1]` (2) because we still haven't moved on.

```
*++ptr
```

Increment `ptr` and dereference the new value of `ptr`, yielding `ptr[2]` (2).

```
++*ptr
```

Dereference `ptr` and increment the stored value, yielding `ptr[2]` (3).

In general the key to understanding problems like this is knowing [operator precedence and associativity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and applying that knowledge in combination with *careful* reading of the code. In this specific case the gotcha is step 3, where `ptr` is only dereferenced and not incremented.

Comment: It would be nice to mention that it's an operator precedence issue, although you do explain it correctly, but you never mentions that.

Comment: @iharob I didn't mention it because I believe the OPs confusion stems from misunderstanding or overlooking step 3, where the pointer is not incremented. The OP demonstrates this by asking about the last two lines, but not the first two lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d ", *ptr);     //*ptr evaluated to 2, print 2
```

You're actually pointing to the second value of your array, which had a value of 1 until you increased it on the previous line